# Build() doesn't run again when returning to a page using the appbar back button, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the app below to print **Build** on the return to the main page from one of the other pages.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/Home',
  routes: {
    '/Home': (context) => Home(),
    '/First': (context) => First(),
    '/Second': (context) => Second(),
  },
),);


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Initialisation');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Homepage')),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First');
          },
          child: Text('Move to the first page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class First extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First')),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/Second', ModalRoute.withName('/Home'));
          },
          child: Text('Move to the second page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondState createState() => _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<Second> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second')),
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I am considering that maybe the `leading` aspect of the `AppBar()` widget can be edited such that this can happen but I'm really not sure.
I would be very grateful for your time and any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: `initState` will only run **exactly once** for each object created. Since when you click to go back your previous page, it was already created, it will never trigger `initState` again

Comment: Okay then how do I get "build" to print when I go back to that page then?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

Comment: Sorry, there isn't that much literature on RouteObservers and I don't quite understand. I'm sure I can figure out how to implement them on my own but I don't really understand how they're meant to be used. How are you suggesting that I use them?

Comment: override `didPush` and `didPopNext` with the code you want executed when the widget route stack changes and the widget ends up on the top. for example call `setState(() => {})` to rebuild the widget

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed` and `Navigator.push` return a future passed by the `pop` method, you may be able to rebuild your page by doing `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First').then(setState(() => {}))` inside your `RaisedButton`

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First').then((_) => setState(() {}));` *

Answer (score 1):

This is by design - when you create a 'page', and the push another page on top of it, and then pop the new page, you want the page underneath to have the same state as before but handle the result of the pop.

To do so, you can await the result of the call to `Navigator.pushNamed`.

That'd look something like this:

```dart
onPressed:: () async {
  final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First');
  // this will be after popping back to this page
  print("pop result: $result");
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that in the part of onPressed after the pop, your code may be running during a build cycle, so you'll want to make sure that if you call `setState` or `Navigator.push` or anything like it, you do it after having deferred that first run.

You can do that either by waiting on a delayed future or using the Scheduler

```
... 
await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
(your code here)
```

Or,

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) => (your code here))
```